# JSON GroupBy 2 attributes - Python

Tags: python, json, pandas-groupby, python-itertools

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to aggregate JSON attributes.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is to groupBy the objects in `'InputTable'` array by two attributes `'To'` and `'TemplateName'`. The JSON template looks as follows:

```
x = {
        "InputTable" : 
        [
            {
                "ServerName":"ServerOne",
                "To":"David", 
                "CC":"Oren", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMOne", 
            },
            {
                "ServerName":"ServerTwo",
                "To":"David", 
                "CC":"", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMOne", 
            },
            {
                "ServerName":"ServerThree",
                "To":"David", 
                "CC":"", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMTwo", 
            },
            {
                "ServerName":"ServerFour",
                "To":"Sam", 
                "CC":"Samer", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMOne", 
            }   
        ]
}
```

Expected results would look something like this, list of lists with grouped objects:

```
[ 
   [

      {
                "ServerName":"ServerOne",
                "To":"David", 
                "CC":"Oren", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMOne"
      },
      {
                "ServerName":"ServerTwo",
                "To":"David", 
                "CC":"", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMOne", 
      },

  ],

  [
      {
                "ServerName":"ServerThree",
                "To":"David", 
                "CC":"", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMTwo", 
      },

  ],

  [
      {
                "ServerName":"ServerFour",
                "To":"Sam", 
                "CC":"Samer", 
                "TemplateName":"LinuxVMOne", 
      }
  ] 



]
```

]

Is it possible to do it without using pandas?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us what have you try ? 
And why do you won't use pandas ?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use Pandas, I'm just asking if there is another way to do it. i'll add my attempts so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

But I think we can do a code more cleaner !

```
y = []
for i in x["InputTable"]:
    if len(y) == 0:
        y.append([i])
    else:
        for j in y:
            if len(j) > 0:
                if j[0]["To"] == i["To"] and j[0]["TemplateName"] == i["TemplateName"]:
                    j.append(i)
                    break
                else:
                    y.append([i])
                    break   
            else:
                y.append([i])
                break
```